# Hold left mouse button in specified window

Tags: mouse

I want to hold left mouse button in pre-definied window. When I normally hold my left mouse button, it affects on active window. I want Linux to hold button in inactive, specified window (PID, name). Thanks.

Comment: with what purpose exactly?

Comment: game, I want it to hold left mouse button in-game, while I browse web.